# Jqgrid: How to cancel/hide delete dialog

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid 4.15

I have add, delete, edit button in the below pager. When the user selects row and click delete, I want to check one cell value and if its equal to something I want to not show the delete dialog, instead show alert that this cannot be deleted.

Some settings of my grid as below:

```
     {
       cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
       guiStyle: "bootstrap",
       sortable: true,
       pager: true,
       formEditing: {           
      closeOnEscape: true,
      closeAfterEdit: true,
      closeAfterAdd: true,
      closeAfterDelete: true,
      savekey: [true, 13],
      addCaption: "Add Me",
      editCaption: "Edit Me ",
      bSubmit: "Submit"                   
    },
   formDeleting: {
    width: 100,
    caption: 'Delete'
   },
  }).jqGrid("navGrid", { add: true, edit:true, del: true, refresh: true, 
 view: false },
    {
    beforeShowForm: function (form) {                     
    }
  },
   {
    beforeShowForm: function (form) {           
    }
}
```

)
     });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide/show the Delete button of the navigator bar depend on the value of from the cell in the row. You can use `onSelectRow` callback for that. The ids of the Delete button (like all other) will be built based on the id of the grid. For example if the grid id is "list" then the id of Delete button in the bottom navigator bar will be `"del_list"` and the id of the same button in the top navigator bar (if you use `toppager: true`) will be `"del_list_top"`. The code wich shows/hides the button can looks close to the following:

```js
onSelectRow (rowid) {
    var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        $delButton = $("#del_" + this.id + ",#del_" + this.id + "_top");
    if (item.closed) {
        $delButton.hide();
    } else {
        $delButton.show();
    }
}
```

One can disable/enable the buttons instead of hiding/showing there alternatively.

Comment: Thanks Oleg this works fine and it hides the delete button in the pager below. Was wondering if there is a way to still show the delete button but when the users clicks the delete button then on the onselect row event I could show some message that they dont have have permission to delete and return false.

Comment: @kaka1234: I'd recommend you to *disable* the buttons and to change the `title` to inform the user that the button is inactive (because of missing permissions for example). The look of the button as enabled invite the user to use it. Displaying the message on click seems me too late. Nevertheless you can use `beforeInitData` callback and return false to abort displaying Delete dialog. You can use `del: false` option of `navGrid` instead of `del: true` if the user don't have delete permission.

Comment: @kaka1234: Alternatively you can use `del: false` option of `navGrid` to remove Delete button and to use `navButtonAdd` to add custom button with the same icon as original Delete button. You can use any custom validation inside of `onClickButton` and to call `delGridRow` from your  `onClickButton` handler only if the user have the corresponding permission.